# Change meta title based on url #id

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a static html website. Our server does not support php/c# etc…

Can JS / JQuery / Ajax or others do the following:

If the url is:

Https://example.com/page , the meta title will be e.g. “home page”.

Https://example.com/example#1 , the meta title will be to “new meta title”

Https://example.com/example#29 , the meta title will be e.g. “a different title”

Effectively , can the meta title be dynamic and displays different text based on what the url #identifier is.

Comment: I think you want to look into the [Hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/hash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
<script>
  function setTitleBasedOnUrlHash() {
    var hash = window.location.hash;
    if (hash === '#1') {
      document.title = 'new meta title';
    } else if (hash === '#2') {
      document.title = 'a different title';
    }
    // ...more else ifs here...
  }

  window.onload = setTitleBasedOnUrlHash;
</script>
```

Comment: What if instead we had parameters in our URL, e.g., /?example=X , what changes would be required to the above?

Comment: To get an object containing all URL parameters, `var urlParameters = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);`. And then to get a specific URL parameter, `var exampleParam = urlParameters.get('example');`. Then, the `if/else` blocks just need to use the new `exampleParam` variable.